# unable to add exception to Bitdefender's Advanced Threat Defense

Tags: bitdefender

I am unable to add an exception to Bitdefender's Advanced Threat Defense. I want to add an exception for the command line (cmd.exe) and bitsadmin.exe in order to be able to download files from the internet to a specific location on my computer. The slider to allow the exception is grayed out.

Comment: Are you an Administrator on this machine?  Are you logged in as an Administrator?  You won't be able to add an exception without being an Administrator

Comment: This is my home computer, as far as I know I am the Administrator. I'm the only one using it. I can add exceptions in the other two areas listed but not for the Advanced Threat Defense slider button.